# String Builder in C# with WCF Host and Client

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, wcf

I have question regarding `StringBuilder` in `C#`. I have process which generates million lines of data. I am using `StringBuilder` as buffer. So whenever I get 20000 lines and I open the file and dump the data into file. Every 20000 lines I dump the data into the file.
Now for this I get one line from processing, so what I do is append the data in new line in the `StringBuilder` object (buffer). But when I use `ToString()` method with the `StringBuilder` it does not convert the data into the `String`.

```
public static stringBuilder Message = new StringBuilder();
```

`Host`

```
for(int i=0; i<20000; i++)
    string Lines = " 20000 Data lines one by one appended";

    Message.AppendLine(Lines);
    Event(EventName, Message.ToString());
```

`Client`

```
Void FileWrite(String Message)
{
     //Stream Writer to write the data into file.
     writeToFile.Write(Message);
     writeToFile.Flush();
}
```

Here my client is the `WCF` client which gets the lines value from processing in Host.
When my event in subscribed it is triggered and it gets the string value of `StringBuffer` and prints it in the file. The method to write in the file is present on the client side. My event is triggered on the client side but the `StringBuilder` value is not printed in the file. can somebody help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. Do you think there's some relationship between a stringbuilder on the server and one on the client?

Comment: You really need to post your actual code, what you've posted is confusing and certainly wouldn't compile

Comment: What I am doing is on server side I am processsing something that will give me 1 line at a time and I am storing that line in StringBuffer object. So I will append 20000 lines in StringBuffer object. ONce I get 20000 lines I will call the callback method of the client in which i pass the StringBuilder object as parameter. In the callback method it will print all 20000 lines to the log file I have. BUt my problem is I am seeing that object being passed to client but it does not dump the values of stringbuilder into file. If I pass only line in the paramter it works.

Comment: So my question is : Is it because of some limitation on capacity of StriingBuilder I am not able to get whole 20000 lines apppended in the StringBuilder object.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to do something like this using [System.Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

```
for(int i=0;i<20000;i++)
    string Lines = " 20000 Data lines one by one appended"+System.Environment.NewLine;
    Message.AppendLine(Lines);
    Event( EventName, Message.ToString());

    Client:
    Void FileWrite(String Message)
    {
     //Stream Writer to write the data into file.
     writeToFile.Write(Message);
     writeToFile.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: Does not Message.AppendLine add a new line character to the Lines?

Comment: AppendLine does add a newline at the end string you are appending.  However, if you are adding multiple lines concatenated into a single string (your code indicates that your for loop does not have brackets around the AppendLine so you are only appending one string) it will only add one newline to your string (not the 20,000 I think you are looking for).  The code is little hard to follow so this is my best guess as to what you are looking for.